# Confused about DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added a `sdf` file to my project then created a table and inserted a few data then  I wrote this code below. But when I run project datagridview looks empty. I have checked that `sdf` file exists.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication6\WindowsFormsApplication6\Database1.sdf");
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from info", con);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

Comment: Be sure you are not overwriting your sdf file when you build/run the project. Select the file and view its properties in visual studio and set the "copy to output" to only if newer

Comment: Your code seems ok, check in datagrid properties that autogeneratecolumns is set to true

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the table has records using the following sequence:

```
cm = new sqlcommand("select count(field_name) from info", con)
iRecords = cm.executescalar

msgbox(iRecords)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to **debug** and see if you are really getting the data into the **DataTable "dt"**.

Check the property for "AutoGenerateColumns" is set to **true**. 
By default **"AutoGenerateColumns"** is **true**,

Still there are chances of overriding.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview